# What's the name of Knowledge sharing activity within scrum metodology

Tags: scrum, knowledge-management

Suppose you work by scrum and set up special meetings to let developers share their knowledge about technologies / experience of the current project parts / enhance collective code ownership.

What is the name of such meetings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standardized name in the Scrum framework.

Call them whatever you think is appropriate so your team knows what it is and your organisation will accept it as part of your work.

I've seen "Workshop", "Product Training" and "Talks", but it's really up to you to pick a name.

Comment: Thank you, now I recalled I heard the term "Workshop"

Answer (score 0):

Scrum includes a Retrospective meeting at the end of each sprint to accomplish what you describe. Make incremental process improvements, ask what is going well, and how to improve. Retrospectives are blameless reviews.

Comment: Retrospective meeting is for discussing all about just ended sprint and not for sharing knowledge

Comment: You could have additional Brown Bag Lunches where one of the team trains the others during lunch time. That could happen during or after a retrospective. Agile means you can customize your process in a less rigid way.